# Mixing static and dynamic (shared) libraries?

Tags: c++, dynamic-linking, static-linking, mixing

I am working with three different libraries, a **Core** (can be compiled as static or DLL), **Graphics** (can be compiled as static or DLL - Dealing with Ogre), **Physics** (can be compiled as static only due to licensing - Havok). A project then uses a combination of the libraries depending on the needs. The **Physics** portion is dependent on some functions of the **Graphics** and **Core** while the **Graphics** is dependent on some functionality of the **Core**. The project works fine with all the libraries statically linked in debug and release. I get the following error when using dynamically linked libraries of the **Core** and **Graphics** but a statically linked **Physics** library.

> Error 1   error LNK2005: "public:
>   unsigned int __thiscall
>   OgreFW::FwErrorLog::GetError(void)"
>   (?GetError@FwErrorLog@OgreFW@@QAEIXZ)
>   already defined in
>   FwCore_d_dll.lib(FwCore_d.dll)    FwHavok_d.lib

I can see what the error means, but I am confused on how to circumvent this. If my libraries are dependant on each other like this, and the licensing of the physics engine (Havok) only allows static linking, do I need to rethink my design (which is a big problem :( ) or is there a way around it?

Thanks

*EDIT: I have already checked to make sure all the libraries are being compiled with **MDd***

*EDIT2: I can use `/FORCE:MULTIPLE` but that is hiding the problem rather than solving it*

*EDIT3: Apologies for several edits. The function **GetError()** is defined in the header, if I place it in the source file, the linking error goes away. Why is that?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but I don't know why it works. There would be an explanation if all the functions (instead of just the one) that were defined in the header gave the linking error, but no, there are only two.

Anyway, the solution is to put the definitions of the functions in the source files. Why does that work? If anybody has an explanation to that, that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

> "The project works fine with all the libraries statically linked in debug and release."

Isn't that your answer then? What advantage would dynamic linking have for this scenario?

Comment: Since it is a framework that is going to be used for many projects, the advantages of DLL will hold (fast linking, updates without recompiling). I would also like to know a solution to this problem rather than side step it.